# Swift4 - не срабатывает метод notify(queue: .main)

Tags: многопоточность, swift4

Есть такой код:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myLabel", attributes: .concurrent)
//создадим группу, в которую поместим нашу очередь
let group = DispatchGroup()

queue.async(group: group) {
    for i in 0...10 {
        if i == 10 {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}

queue.async(group: group) {
    for i in 0...20 {
        if i == 20 {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}

//мы хотим, чтобы уведомление пошло в наш DispatchQueue.main
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print("Всё закончено в группе: group")
}
```

По идее должен сработать notify(), но он не срабатывает. В консоли выводится только:

```
20
10
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Вопрос: почему так происходит и как заставить работать метод notify()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение простое: в конце кода нужно дописать

```
RunLoop.main.run()
```